# Regex to find the code blocks in a C# program

Tags: c#, regex

I have to find the code blocks from the given code using a regex in C#.

e.g. I have to find the For loop block from the following code

```
For A in 1..10 
Loop
stmt1;
For C in cur_op
Loop
stmt2;
end loop;
end loop;
For T in 4..8
loop
stmt3;
end loop;
```

I want to retrieve the code blocks as

```
For A in 1..10 
Loop
stmt1;
For C in cur_op
Loop
stmt2;
end loop;
end loop;
```

and

```
For T in 4..8
loop
stmt3;
end loop;
```

Can anyone suggest me a regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You're asking for a regex parsing a context-free language, and while Perl REs actually can parse CFLs, I'm not sure C# regular expressions can do it, and using it is not the biggest pleasure out there.

Natural solution for your problem would be to create a parser for the language, and get the info from that. You could use a parser generator like CoCo/R or ANTLR.

Comment: i had thought of using parser. But because of few reasons i decided to implement the parsing in C# only. One of those reasons is i need to write the code to parse multiple languages.So will have to write grammar for all of them. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's possible to do that with .net Regex, and if you really don't need a real parser, you can go for this solution. It is nicely explained in [this article on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Nested_RegEx_explained.aspx) and I can confirm you that it works well (I used that to implement a simple bbcode parser).

You pattern might look like something like that :

```
String pattern = @"
(?# line 01) For ... in ...
(?# line 02) (?>
(?# line 03)   For ... in ... (?<DEPTH>)
(?# line 04)   |
(?# line 05)   end loop; (?<-DEPTH>)
(?# line 06)   |
(?# line 07)   .?
(?# line 08) )*
(?# line 09) (?(DEPTH)(?!))
(?# line 10) end loop;
";
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but it is not quite useful since the structure of the code is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Balancing with a Regex is not that obvious since you need to properly match the outer-most `For.. end loop;`.

It could be simpler with a basic loop going through each line, incrementing a counter when it contains `FOR` and decreasing it when it contains `end loop;`.
While the counter is positive, you append the current line to your result.
When the counter reaches 0, you've got your block.

I've proposed something [similar recently for another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression/601926#601926).

This is fine and easy if all you need is getting the inner blocks between `For..end loop;`.

As jpalecek said, if you need to do more, you would be better off using a more appropriate parsing method or your job will become increasingly difficult.

Comment: i have considered this kind of programming.
but i thought if only single regex can get me what i want then it would be far more easier. anyway, thanks for the suggestion.