# Filtering data from file

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, data-structures

I've got around 50 lines of data in a text file below containing the following

```
Date= 1/1/2012 (dd:mm:yyyy) Time= 1:44:10 (hh:mm:ss)
Recording Started at 1:44:10 (hh:mm:ss)
X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001
X-Value = -0.755030, Y-Value = 7.861651, Z-Value = 6.016289, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23208
X-Value = -0.448467, Y-Value = 8.551417, Z-Value = 4.943320, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23401
Recording Stopped at 1:44:11 (hh:mm:ss)
```

The code I have right now uses a BufferedReader reading every line of the file but what I really want to do is extract the Y-Value, Z-Value and Timestamp(milliseconds) values from each line and then store it in some sort of data structure?  What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with `comma and white-spae` as a delimiter and than split the resultant array element with `=` as a delimiter. Than, add the resultant array elements into an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
String str = "X-Value = -0.525108, Y-Value = 7.746691, Z-Value = 5.863008, Timestamp(milliseconds) = 23001
";
String[] data_array = str.split(", ");    
ArrayList<String> Y_Value = new ArrayList<String>();
Y_Value.add(data_array[1].split("= ")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've answered your own question - use a regex ([Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) to extract the values from each line and store it in a data structure that is appropriate for your situation. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression) for an example. This is assuming that you want only the values themselves and not the identifiers.