# Change the specific word's color in the row JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to figure out how can I change the color of word which is in the row in JTable.

For example this is my sentence which in one row;

dmpsrv log "Tue Mar 12 15:33:03 2013" (GMT) (DB=SS@2) pid=662 `user="s46"` node="B2-W4" execution time=1(s)

In every row the structure is same and I want to show the user name in `bold`.

But I don't know how can I do it ? Does any one give some trick ?

Thanks.

Comment: easiest of ways is to use Html in Renderer

Comment: For this tutorial or example , how can i search this topic ?

Comment: I think that you would search in posts by @camickr, but your structure in form `dmpsrv log "Tue Mar 12 15:33:03 2013" (GMT) (DB=SS@2) pid=662 user="s46" node="B2-W4" execution time=1(s)` talking about four-five columns (correct me if Im wrong:-), then you can to forget about something special to put to the Renderer, just follows Oracle tutorial, bunch of code in SSCCE form here

Comment: I have only one column, also do you think that if I use JtextFields, will it be more easy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mKorbel stated you can use HTML tags in Swing: [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Also you'll need a custom cell renderer: [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

**Example**

This is **just an example** of implementation (it's not *exactly* what you need) but you can manage to make it more accurate:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        String str = value.toString();
        String regex = ".*?user=\".*?\".*?";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            regex = "user=\".*?\"";
            matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
            while(matcher.find()){
                String aux = matcher.group();
                str = str.replace(aux, "<b>" + aux + "</b>");
            }
            str = "<html>" + str + "</html>";

            setText(str);
        }                
        return this;                
    }            
});
```

This renderer looks for `user="whateverHere"` pattern in the string. If it matches then replaces all instances of this sub-string with the same sub-string sorrounded by `<b></b>` tags. Finally sorrounds the whole text with `<html></html>` tags.

More info about regex in this Q&A: [Using Java to find substring of a bigger string using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

As `DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends from `JLabel` (yes, a Swing component!) HTML tags will do the trick.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try and search on this solution !

Comment: You're welcome! :) Hope it was helpful. But read the tutorials carefully to understand how Swing works ;)