# Removing trailing characters after email address with Regex

Tags: java, regex, email-validation

I am using regex to identify if a string is a valid email address or not. Pattern:

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
    "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

The problem is that this regex pattern cannot correctly identify the email address if it contains a trailing character. e.g: "test@example.com." or "test@example.com,"

Do you know of a regex pattern that can take this into account?

Comment: Well, `foo@bar.com,` (note the trailing comma) _is_ an invalid email address...

Comment: This regex produces a lot of false negative, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: Also take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `$` sign, use `[.,]?` or any other punctuation(inside that `[]`) if you want to be there to overcome this.

```
+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})[.,]?$";
                                                   ^^^^^
```