# Selenium with Java: use split() with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, split

I have a string with multiple delimiters, i.e. `,':|£`. I want to extract only the number from the string, along with the currency symbol. I tried many possible ways but was unsuccessful. Could someone help me with this.

The entire string is given below. I want to extract only the currency, like `£340,346`

```
chartInfoValues(event,'Investment Activity Graph','','Year:|2014|Current:|£340,346|Recommended:|£340,346','aa709fd2','220','80')
```

Comment: did you try to use [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)?

Answer (score 1):

also I would recommend you to look at the [StringTokenizer](http://www.javatpoint.com/string-tokenizer-in-java) java class
Taking an example from the  documenation:
"my name is khan"-splitting  on the basis of whitespace

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("my name is khan"," ");  
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {  
         System.out.println(st.nextToken());  
     }
```

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is the regex to use for String.split()? If so this works:

`(£[0-9]*),[0-9]`*

slighty tidier approach:

```
£(\d*,\d*)
```