# Java Regex cant save text to string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to save the bolded text to a string.
I have come up with the regex "routeName?.+?routeLengthKM"   and according to an online regex tester this should get me what I want with the find method but it is only returning true/false.   How can i save the bolded text to a string?

"routes:[{**routeName:Dulles Toll Rd W; SR-28 S,routeDurationInMinutes:18**,routeLengthKM:21.474,routeLengthMiles:13.343320854,toll:true},{**routeName:Frying Pan Rd; SR-28 S,routeDurationInMinutes:18**,routeLengthKM:19.437,routeLengthMiles:12.077588127,toll:false}

```
package regex;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class regexclass {

  public static void main (String args[]){
    Pattern p= Pattern.compile("routeName?.+?routeLengthKM");
    Matcher m= p.matcher("routes:[{routeName:Dulles Toll Rd W; SR-28 S,routeDurationInMinutes:18,routeLengthKM:21.474,routeLengthMiles:13.343320854,toll:true},{routeName:Frying Pan Rd; SR-28 S,routeDurationInMinutes:18,routeLengthKM:19.437,routeLengthMiles:12.077588127,toll:false}]");
    System.out.println(m.find());

  }
}
```

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see. Please add it.

Comment: there is not much to see. I just need to know how to get the bolded text to a string

Comment: Have you tried something like this answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression>?

Comment: yes i tried that but it gives me an outofbounds exception saying "no group 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m.find();` will launch the matching engine. This will try to match the regex against the text. It returns `true` if a match could be found, and `false` if no match could be found. Normally, you would use a construct like this to find all matches:

`while(m.find()) {}`

After having found a match (i.e. after `m.find();` or better `if (m.find()) {`), you can retrieve the match with `m.group(n);` with `n` the group number. 0 is the full match group and all other numbers up from there (1,2,3,...) refer to subgroups (things in parentheses).