# Regular expression to fetch lines evaluating only one part of a string, java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find the regular expression to match only a part of the pattern

For an example text is :

```
GoodClass.NiceMethod
BadClass.NiceMethod
Badclass2.NiceMethod
Verybadclass.NiceMethod
GoodClass.NiceMethod
BadClass.NiceMethod
Badclass2.NiceMethod
GoodClass.NiceMethod
```

how can I get all lines where 'NiceMethod' does not follow 'GoodClass'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Java to find substring of a bigger string using Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *negative lookbehind*:

```
String regex = "(?<!GoodClass\\.)\\bNiceMethod\\b";
```

Comment: You typo'ed `Good` as `GooD`, and the code also allow `VeryNiceMethod` to match.