# Reading particular String from a line

Tags: java

I am using this to get each line from a text file using Java Class.

```
String line = null;
try{    
       BufferedReader Br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/data/local/fileconfig.txt"));   

       while ((line = Br.readLine()) != null)
        {
           Log.d("hi", "LINE : " + line);              
        }
     } catch (Throwable throwable) { }
```

The fileconfig.txt has 2 lines like this -

```
############################################
packagename:com.hello
```

So my Log is like -

```
LINE :  ############################################
LINE :  packagename:com.hello
```

My question is now I am able to get this line info packagename:com.hello. I just want to extract com.hello out of this line. What is the logic I can use in my while loop?

Comment: Try a regex. group 1 in "packagename:\\s*([^\\s]+)"  would contain your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of line is always the same then this should do:

```
Log.d("hi", "LINE : " + line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(":")+1));
```

Comment: This is giving me output as -
LINE : ############################################
LINE : com.hello

Comment: @FAZ Don't read the 1st line, break it or use a `startsWith("package");`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method.

Or, somewhat more powerful, but also more difficult, use Regular Expressions with Match Groups.

See here: [Using Java to find substring of a bigger string using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either RegEx or a simple `split()` from `String`

```
:?(.*)
```

or split

```
String myString = "dsd:Example";
myString.split(":");
```