# delete some numbers and minus with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a link and I wanna number in this link.

```
<a title="HALKALININ EN G&#214;ZDE PROJESİ BOSPHORUS CITYDE SAHİBİNDEN SATILIK" class="overlay-link" href="/konut-satilik/istanbul-kucukcekmece-halkali-merkez-sahibinden-apartman-dairesi/detay/25118422"></a>
```

I tried

```
content.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", "")
```

but output is wrong. I wanna numbers after `/detay/`

output:

```
214--------25118422
```

Comment: Please tell us what you tried and provide some sample code where you got stuck.

Comment: `/\d+$/` ........ if look-behind supports then `/(?<=-)\d+/`

Comment: Welcome Johny. Please show your code that didn't work and specify regex flavor. Most people here don't answer "give me regex" questions as long as they aren't interesting problems or show at least a bit of own research effort :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan it doesn't worked.

Comment: @bobblebubble ty. I edited question.

Comment: @Psi I am new in regex. I read some topics in stackoverflow but they didn't worked for me.

Comment: If you just need the number after `/detay/` how about using a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for extraction like this: `/detay/(\\d+)` with [`find()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/600740/5527985) -> `group(1)`. Also see [regex reference here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: @bobblebubble it worked. ty :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for extracting the ID from the link. See the example below:

```
    String content = "<a title=\"HALKALININ EN G&#214;ZDE PROJESİ BOSPHORUS CITYDE SAHİBİNDEN SATILIK\" class=\"overlay-link\" href=\"/konut-satilik/istanbul-kucukcekmece-halkali-merkez-sahibinden-apartman-dairesi/detay/25118422\"></a>";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("/detay/([0-9]+)").matcher(content);

    String linkId = null;
    if (matcher.find()) {
        linkId = matcher.group(1);
    }

    System.out.println("linkId: " + linkId);
```

---

Hope this helps!