# Get one particular index string present on a line of List<String>

Tags: java

I got the next code with the objective of read a file, and print the third string present on a line, the file is like that:

```
Reforma_Protestante - ABSTRACCAO|ACONTECIMENTO - IDEIA|EFEMERIDE
Europa - LOCAL - HUMANO
Cativeiro_Babilónica_da_igreja - ACONTECIMENTO - EFEMERIDE
Avignon - ACONTECIMENTO - EVENTO
```

The code I get only prints the lines of the text:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"));
...
for (int xi=0;xi < lines.size();xi++)
{
    if(lines.get(xi).contains(tt[2]))
    {
        System.out.println(lines.indexOf(lines) );
        com+= tt[0]+"\t"+tt[1]+"\t"+tt[2]+"\t"+"LINES.INDEXOF(2)"+"\t"+"LINES.INDEXOF(4)"+"\t"+tt[5]+"\t"+dt.get(tt[6])+"\n";
        lines.remove(xi);
    }
}
...
```

I want in the spot of **LINES.INDEXOF(2)** the word present on the file line(xi) and index 2, so it this case the fist one should be **ABSTRACCAO|ACONTECIMENTO**

And in the spot on **LINES.INDEXOF(4)** I want **IDEIA|EFEMERIDE**

I've tried `lines.get(xi).indexof(2)`, but the output was -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just get the text from one line and with a REGEX extract the Nth word?

```
/ (?:\b\w+\b){Nth} /
```

Here how to search against a string with regex
https://stackoverflow.com/a/600740/6726261

Comment: Maybe with a map HashMap, and iterate key and value??