# Pattern in java regEx does not match

Tags: java, regex

This is my first post.
I want to extract some special pattern from a String. 
I searched and found this answer [Using Java to find substring of a bigger string using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

This was exactly what i needed. 
Unfortunatly it does not work

My Code looks like this:

```
String next = ">GID1_seq1 ABW28161.1 lipid-A-disaccharide synthase, putative [Acaryochloris marina MBIC11017]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(next);
        if(m.matches()){
            Pattern p1 =  Pattern.compile("GID\\d*_seq\\d*");
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(next);
            if(m1.matches()) {
                System.out.println(m1.group(2));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("not a match");
            }




        }
```

But it does not work i also tried to just match on 
"GID1_seq1" but also this does not work where is my problem ?

Edit: forget about the m1.group(2) 
i get "not a match" everytime

Comment: `matches("GID\\d*_seq\\d*")` will try to match the whole string, it fails right there. The question about why `.group(2)` is empty - there are no capturing groups in your pattern. Just add two pairs of unescaped `(...)` in the pattern, and it will be populated if you use `.find()` and there is a match.

Comment: ok thanks but how do i get the subseqence extracted like i want the output "GID1_seq1" as substring is there no way to get it ?

Comment: https://ideone.com/nyvNgc