# Start of the line regex usage in java Pattern.matches method?

Tags: java, regex

I am a little bit confused about the `^` symbol in regex.

From what I read online it means : *"Finds regex that must match at the beginning of the line."*

I read about the example presented here : https://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end

" In the example above, we can use the pattern `^success` to match only a line that begins with the word "success", but not the line `Error: unsuccessful operation`

My confusion comes from the fact that `^success` will only match with the string "success" right ? So what is the point of `^` In the examples below ? I would have expect the second to also be true, based on the description of the `^` symbol.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^success","success"));  // true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^success","success is good"));  // false
```

Can anyone give me any clear examples with this `^` symbol used in regex?

Comment: `Pattern.matches` tests if regex matches *whole* string, not if some part can be matched by it. That is why `Pattern.matches("^success","success is good")` returns `false`

Comment: ^success anything that starts with and has string success only.  so it wont match "success is good" its equal to ^success$

Comment: @all Then how can I make the check so that the word "success" is first in a string like "success is good" ? Should I have a regular expression that verifies the success part, followed by any number of characters?

Comment: @user1653941: Interesting, in many other regex `^success` would not be equal to `^success$` as it would still continue matching. Strange way for `Java` to handle it.

Comment: @l'L'l it's about the method `matches()`, which checks for a *full match* of the entire string!

Comment: @mumpitz: Thank you for that, otherwise I was going to say wow... that's insane.

Comment: @l'L'l, if using ^ and or $ , a multiline mode pattern ie  "(?m)^success$" will making matching different if using matcher.find().  ie in multiline mode find will match at the start and end of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `^success` only **matches** the string "success".
But `^success` still is a pattern to be found in a string like "success is good".

You could check...

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("^success.*","success is good"));
```

...which should be true, because it matches strings that start with "success" and contain any more characters.
OR you can try to **find** the pattern `^success` in a string. It's a problem of terminology. A pattern **matches** a string only if it **matches** the whole string *completely*. To **find** a pattern as part of a string (so a substring of it *matches* the pattern) is a different thing!

A **full match** of a string also implies `^` and `$` (for beginning and end of the string) in the pattern, because the string has to match from beginning to end (thanks to @Pshemo for pointing that out!).

Also see: [Using Java to find substring of a bigger string using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600733/using-java-to-find-substring-of-a-bigger-string-using-regular-expression)

Comment: `System.out.println(Pattern.matches("success.*","success is good")); // is also true` ...so your answer made it clearer...but still not 100% why ^ is needed

Comment: @Teshte But it doesn't match "my success is good", because "success" is not the beginning, so there's a difference!

Comment: @Teshte ^ is not needed for `matches()` since it already requires from regex to match *whole* string (from beginning till its end, so it is like regex is *implicitly* surrounded with `^` and `$`). `^` is useful when you are using `Matcher#find` method, which iterates over *substrings* matching regex.

Comment: @Pshemo exactly, thank you for pointing that out! I will add this to the answer.

Comment: And now you have 2 problems!
`.*` is evil. I learned that the hard way.

Comment: @AdityaGupta True, but it's just an example to clarify that there *can* be more after `^success`. The problems that arise with `.*` are a different story. That's **not** what this question is about. It's about the mechanics of `^` in RegEx to match the beginning of strings!

Comment: Makes sense. It's just that users copy a working code and leave it as is in the code. Even static code analyzers don't pick these things.

Comment: @AdityaGupta Well, as bad as `.*` can be, the OP asked how to actually use `^` to match a string that starts with a certain pattern, whatever comes after that. In Java, the given RegEx does just that.